# How to convert H.264 stream into sequence of small video files

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, video-capture, h.264

We have a video-stream coming from camera.

We need to store it by 2 minute-videos, e.g. 9-00_9-02.avi, 9-02_9-04.avi, etc.

The incoming stream is 1080p RAW.
We connect it to BlackMagic H.264 Pro Recorder so on the output we have H.264@720p@somebitrate.

However, it's still either a stream, or ONE big file.

Is there an option to automatically cut it into sequence?

Thanks!